# String array to sentence ruby 1.9.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-1.9.3

I have tried to convert it to the array and then try to use `join(',')` but this is not converting in a sentence can any buddy help on it.
 convert this string

`"[\"one\", \"two\", \"three\"]"`

to sentence `one, two, three`

**Updated**:

**Solved this by `gsub`

`.gsub(/(\[\"|\"\])/, '').split('", "')`

I have used this and got `[" one", "two", "three"]`,  is there any other way to convert it like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely not the prettiest of solutions, but you could have done something like:

```
eval("[\"one\", \"two\", \"three\"]")
```

Comment: it will give all to gather in one string , it should be like "one", "two", "three" but in this it will be like "one, two, three, four"

Comment: Ohw, well in that case it's somewhat easier, remove the .join.

I'll update my answer :)